# UPDATE IF EXISTS Query

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to UPDATE a record if there is a row in the table. After updating  a record I would like to return TRUE from my method. I am using the following query. I am using SQL server 2005. How do I know if my SQL query updated the table? Please let me know.

```
Private Boolean UpdateTable()
{
  string sql = "IF EXISTS(Select A.CNum FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.CID= B.CID AND   A.CNum is NULL AND CID=@cID) BEGIN ..... END" 

}
```

Thank you..

Comment: Returning the rows affected via the RowsAffected = obj.ExecuteNonQuery() may result in a -1 value if using the keywords SET NOCOUNT ON. It might be better to stick with returning the count through an OUTPUT parameter or a SELECT RowsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT recordset - just in case you are using SET NOCOUNT ON.

If you're going to retrieve the RowsUpdated versions below, don't use the SET NOCOUNT ON keywords, but IMHO I always turn on the SET NOCOUNT ON; becaus the hit is so expensive, in my Standards and Best Practices Book I use it all the time. That's why I wanted to warn you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you execute a batch of SQL, you should be notified of how many rows were modified / inserted / updated, either as the return value from your e.g. `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` call:

```
Private Boolean UpdateTable()
{
    int rowsUpdated = 0;

    string sql = "IF EXISTS(Select A.CNum FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.CID= B.CID AND   A.CNum is NULL AND CID=@cID) BEGIN ..... END" 

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string-here"))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) 
        {
           con.Open();
           rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();
        }
    }

    return (rowsUpdated > 0);
}
```

or you can query the `@@ROWCOUNT` property in your SQL statement after the `UPDATE`:

```
...
BEGIN
   UPDATE ........

   DECLARE @Updated INT
   SELECT @Updated = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

You can return that value, or check for a value of larger than zero or whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like there is a problem with my SQL query. How can I write update statement with JOIN condition?
UPDATE TABLEA SET CNUM= @cnum FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.CID= B.CID AND   A.CNum is NULL AND CID=@cID

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. Here is my Query. I don't know this is right way.
IF EXISTS(Select A.CNum FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.CID= B.CID AND   A.CNum is NULL AND CID=@cID)
BEGIN 
DECLARE @Updated INT 
UPDATE TABLEA SET CNUM= 'test' FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.CID= B.CID AND A.CNum is NULL AND CID=@cID 
SELECT @Updated = @@ROWCOUNT 
END

Comment: @nav100: putting large code snippets in comments is not a good thing - they can't be formatted to look good. Why don't you just update your original question (by editing it) with your final solution? That would be more useful to all of us! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your query with [Sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) and that will return the number of affected rows (1 or 0).